# Discord.py | Pillow ImageFilter

Tags: discord.py, python-imaging-library, imagefilter

**Code Task**: 
When using the command, the bot takes a photo of the user or the one whom the user has marked and adds a blur effect.

**My code problem**: 
After looking through quite a lot of sources to complete my task, I could not find a detailed answer. In my opinion, my code looks fine, but it does not work, but despite the fact that no error is output.

Code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

@Bot.command()
async def blur(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    async with ctx.channel.typing():
        await ctx.message.delete()
        url = user.avatar_url
        image = Image.open(url)
        blurred_url = image.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
        blurred_url.save("sas.png")
        file = discord.File("sas.png", filename="sas.png")
        await ctx.send(file=file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to my problem:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

@Bot.command()
async def blur(ctx, user: discord.Member = None):
    if user is None: user = ctx.author
    async with ctx.channel.typing():
        await ctx.message.delete()
        url = user.avatar_url
        req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        resource = urlopen(req)
        avatar = open("avatar.png", 'wb')
        avatar.write(resource.read())
        avatar.close()
        image = Image.open('avatar.png')
        blurred_url = image.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
        blurred_url.save("sas.png")
        file = discord.File("sas.png", filename="sas.png")
        await ctx.send(file=file)

Bot.run('TOKEN')
```

I haven't solved the problem. So I do not know if I can help you with questions related to the code. Good luck. Good luck.

The code is working

Answer (score 0):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import io

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def aipic(ctx):
    # Create a new image with a white background
    image = Image.new("RGB", (500, 500), "white")

    # Draw a red circle in the center of the image
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    draw.ellipse((200, 200, 300, 300), fill="red")

    # Draw a green rectangle on the right side of the image
    draw.rectangle((350, 200, 450, 300), fill="green")

    # Save the image to a byte buffer
    with io.BytesIO() as image_binary:
        image.save(image_binary, 'PNG')
        image_binary.seek(0)
        file = discord.File(fp=image_binary, filename='aipic.png')

        # Send the image to the Discord channel where the command was invoked
        await ctx.send(file=file)

# Run the bot with your bot token
bot.run('your_bot_token_here')
```